# PutDatabaseRecord max wait time does not work as expected

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm working with `NIFI` and `PutDataBaseRecord` to insert records to tables. I am simulating the case that the database is down in order to handle the error (to send an mail indicating connection time out for example ). The problem is when I disconnect the net cable to simulate the error and turns on `PutDataBaseRecord` the flows do not pass either to the relationship of failure, or to the relationship of retry and the processor sends bulletin error messages continually, it never stops  sending messages.

I put 10 seconds in the **Max wait time** property with the hope that after that time the processor stops throwing errors and sends the flows to the fault relationship, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the option is not working as you expected. See [HERE](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/index.html).

> Max Wait Time: The maximum amount of time allowed for *a running SQL statement*, zero means there is no limit. Max time less than 1 second will be equal to zero.
> Supports Expression Language: true (will be evaluated using variable registry only)

Since you are using PutDatabaseRecords processor, it will assume the database connection is well done. The error with this processor should be related to the SQL, not connection problem and so database connection failure is not going to *failure* relationship, I guess.